# Having trouble building jekyll locally and deploying to gh-pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

A few months ago, I set up a site using jekyll and it's hosted on github pages here: http://sethxd.github.io. Originally, I just figured I'd let github pages handle the building because I wouldn't need to use plugins.

Well, now I'd like to use plugins. I've tried to follow a few tutorials online to set up a separate source branch, but I keep running into git errors and conflicts. I'd also like to set up a rakefile or other tool to build and deploy this automatically in the future.

I'm on Windows, running Jekyll 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages doesn't allow using most of [Jekyll plugins](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/) for security reasons, but [some can be used](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/). The only way to deploy a Jekyll website to GitHub that uses plugins is via `_site` folder. You only upload the content of this folder, so GitHub won't build the site for you, it will display it as simple html.